# Mercurial Hook to Execute Pulled SQL Files After Update

Tags: sql-server, mercurial, atlassian-sourcetree, mercurial-hook

I am using SourceTree with a Mercurial BitBucket repository. I would like for any SQL script files (*.sql) pulled from my remote BitBucket repo into my local one to simply be executed immediately after I update my working copy with the pulled files.  The DB connection info would always be the same.

What would be the simplest way to accomplish this with either SourceTree itself or perhaps a mercurial hook? In the latter case, I believe something could be done with an update hook, but I'm not exactly sure how to set one up.

I am running SQL server 2012 on a Windows 7 machine.

Comment: I dont think you do want that. Perhaps after updating, but pulling is just bringing the remote changes into your local repository. It doesnt actually update your working files, and so the new script wont actually be present.

Comment: Edited accordingly - thanks